# unable to find the right regex

Tags: python, regex

here are some of the loglines:

```
2014-12-04T03:44:55.059+0000: 3155402.861: [GC 3155402.861: [ParNew: 52663K->161K(59008K), 0.0037300 secs] 81475K->28973K(104200K), **0.0038550** secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs]

2014-12-04T04:26:31.955+0000: 3157899.757: [GC 3157899.757: [ParNew: 52641K->161K(59008K), 0.0014220 secs] 81453K->28973K(104200K), **0.0015160** secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.01, real=0.00 secs]

2014-12-04T05:08:48.764+0000: 3160436.567: [GC 3160436.567: [ParNew: 52641K->163K(59008K), 0.0028550 secs] 81453K->28975K(104200K), **0.0029850** secs]
```

I want to filter for values highlighted in '**'

Here is my regex. It works except for the last line

```
patt = re.compile(r'''\[GC.*([0-9]+\.[0-9]+).secs\].+\[.*''')
```

Here is another regex which only works on last line but none of the other lines

```
patt = re.compile(r'''\[GC.*([0-9]+\.[0-9]+).secs\].?''')
```

I need help with coming up with a generic reg ex that will fetch the value exactly...any help greatly appreciated

Comment: you want `**0.0038550**` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Positive look aheads will be helpfull

The regex can be

```
GC.*?([\d.]+)(?= secs\](?: \[Time|$))
```

[**Regex Example**](http://regex101.com/r/jX4wF6/1)

- `(?= secs\](?: \[Time|$)` postive look ahead. Asserts that the digits are followed by `secs] [Time` or  end of string `$`

**Example Usage**

```
>>> str="""2014-12-04T03:44:55.059+0000: 3155402.861: [GC 3155402.861: [ParNew: 52663K->161K(59008K), 0.0037300 secs] 81475K->28973K(104200K), 0.0038550 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs]"""
>>> str1="""2014-12-04T05:08:48.764+0000: 3160436.567: [GC 3160436.567: [ParNew: 52641K->163K(59008K), 0.0028550 secs] 81453K->28975K(104200K), 0.0029850 secs]"""
>>> str2="""2014-12-04T04:26:31.955+0000: 3157899.757: [GC 3157899.757: [ParNew: 52641K->161K(59008K), 0.0014220 secs] 81453K->28973K(104200K), 0.0015160 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.01, real=0.00 secs]"""

>>> re.findall(r'GC.*?([\d.]+)(?= secs\](?: \[Time|$))', str2)                                                                                                                 
['0.0015160']
>>> re.findall(r'GC.*?([\d.]+)(?= secs\](?: \[Time|$))', str1)
['0.0029850']
>>> re.findall(r'GC.*?([\d.]+)(?= secs\](?: \[Time|$))', str)
['0.0038550']
>>>
```

Comment: plus 1 for a complete answer. thank you and accepting

Answer (score 1):

You can use [positive look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
>>> re.findall(r' [\d\.]+ (?=sec)',s)
[' 0.0037300 ', ' 0.0014220 ', ' 0.0028550 ']
```

Comment: plus 1 for mentioning about positive look ahead